# Как умножать сгенерированые переменные не зная их?

Tags: python

```
import random

def number_save():
    da = randint(1, 100)
    if not da == "":
        number_save()

number_save() * number_save() # не робит
```

Comment: А шо вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Что-то как-то вообще совершенно непонятно, чего вы этим кодом хотели добиться

Comment: я хочу сгенерировать рандомные переменные и умножить их

Comment: выравнивание кода там где нужно?

Comment: @coreD «сгенерировать рандомные переменные и умножить их» — просто `result = random.randint(1, 100) * random.randint(1, 100)`

Comment: Вы написали некорректную рекурсивную функцию, т.е. функцию которая вызывает саму себя и никогда не возвращает результат. По сути это бесконечный цикл. Когда пишется рекурсивная функция - обычно начинать нужно с условия выхода

Comment: да я забыл из дефа убрать умножение

Comment: @coreD Таки зачем вы сравниваете число со строкой? У вас из-за этого бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: какой смысл вложен в ``if not da == "":``?

Answer (score 6):

```
from random import randint
def number_save():
    return randint(1, 100)

print(number_save() * number_save())
```

Чтоб вернуть переменную используйте `return`